# Solve 2nd order ODE: $\ddot{x} + a\dot{x} = b$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can you solve a second order differential equation of form: $\ddot{x} + a\dot{x} = b$? What type of equation is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second order linear differential equation.
$$\ddot{x} + a\dot{x} = b$$
Integrate directly:
$$\dot{x} + a{x} = bt+K$$
You can surely solve a first order differential equation...

Comment: Thank you. What's the reason why we can simply integrate?

Comment: You're welcome Alex You have only constants and derivatives  so that you can perform integration here  and reduce the order of the differential equation @Alex

Answer (score 0):

It's a second order nonhomogeneous linear equation with linear coefficients. Since it's linear, you can split it into homogeneous and particular solutions. For the homogeneous solution, you can take $D$ as the differential operator, and then the equation is $D^2x+aDx = 0$ or $(D^2+aD)x=0$. This factors into $D(D+a)x =0$. If $Dx = 0$, $x=C_1$. If $(D+a)x =0$, then $x = C_2e^{-at}$. This gives the homogeneous solution $x = C_1+C_2e^{-at}$.

For the particular solution, we can take the general polynomial $p(t)=c_0+c_1t+c_2t^2$ and require $p''+ap'=b$. The RHS has no $t$ term, and $p''$ has no $t$ term, so $p'$ must have no $t$ term, which mean that $p$ has no $t^2$. That means that $p''$ is zero, so $ap'=b$, and hence $p = \frac b a t$ (we don't need the constant when we do the indefinite integral, since that's already in the homogeneous solution).

Combining the homogeneous and particular solutions, we get $x = C_1+C_2e^{-at}+\frac b a t$

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer.